# What is the fastest way to upload a huge data set to Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, upload

I have some 4000+ records to be uploaded on the App Engine.
Does GAE allow you to upload so much data? If yes, then I have some
questions:

1. How to upload that data?
2. How much time will it take to complete this thing?
3. What is the fastest method to upload it.

---

**duplicate of: [How do you upload data in bulk to Google App Engine Datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741599/how-does-one-upload-data-in-bulk-to-a-google-appengine-datastore)**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

Aral Balkans GAEBAR (google backup and restore) http://aralbalkan.com/1784

google bulkloader
 http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html